# iterate inside a new JQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to pass some html code as a parameter, however, before I pass it, I need to change some src attribute values.

I cannot use lastIndexOf or any of those to modify the html value since I don't know which value the src's will have.

What I'm trying to do then, is to create an object containing the html, and then alter that object only. I don't want to alter the actual webpage.

is this possible??

What I did first was this:

```
$('[myImages]').each(function() {
var urlImg = "../tmpFiles/fileName" + counter;
$(this).attr('src', urlImg);
counter++;
});
```

So finally, I had the desired code like this:

```
myformData = { theChartCode: $('#TheDivContainingTheHTML').html() }
```

However, this actually changes the image sources on the webpage, which I don't want to.

Then I thought I could create a JQuery object with the html so I could alter that object only like this:

```
var $jQueryObject = $($.parseHTML($('#TheDivContainingTheHTML').html()));
```

But now, I can't figure out how to iterate within that object in order to change the src attribute's values of the desired images.

Any help will be really appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do It. First would be creating a clone of target element and use the same on the Fly. You can do like below:

var Elem = $('#TheDivContainingTheHTML').clone();

now do whatever you want like iterate, alter,insert,remove.

var allImages =$(Elem).children("img");

Thanks Much!

Comment: thanks a lot!! however, clone is actually cloning the element (which is a form, by the way) but children("img") is not getting any objects.
var theClone = $('#TheDivContainingTheHTML').clone();
var allImages = $(theClone).children("img");
alert(allImages.length);
this returns 0, and there are about 6 images in there, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: var imagesArray = $(theClone).find("img").each(function(index){ ... }); is what I was looking for.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks @Sergio yes I assumed that images first level chaildren of div but in your case its inner level so above  1 you found is perfect! Thanks for apreciating

Answer (score 2):

Depending on when you want to change the object, solution will be different. Let's pretend you want to change it after you click another element in the page. Your code will look like that :

```
var clonedHTML;
$('#clickable-element').click(function() {
    var $originalHTML = $(this).find('.html-block');
    var $cloneHTML = $originalHTML.clone();
    $cloneHTML.find('.my-image').attr('src', 'newSrcValue');

    clonedHTML = $cloneHTML.clone();
    return false; //Prevents click to be propagated
});

//Now you can use `clonedHTML`
```

The key point here is the clone method : http://api.jquery.com/clone/.

Comment: But at the end of the day, what I need is the whole html once these small changes are done, but the html has a lot more of code.

I need the pass the parameter like this:
    myformData = { theChartCode: $('somethingIdontKnow').html() }

What do I earn by having these cloned images??

Answer (score 1):

You can `clone` the elements:

```
var outerHTML = $collection.clone().attr('src', function(index) {
    return "../tmpFiles/fileName" + index;
}).wrapAll('<div/>').parent().html();
```

You can also use the `map` method:

```
var arr = $collection.map(function(i) {
     return $(this).clone().attr('src', '...').prop('outerHTML');
}).get();
```